# How to copy paste my Mvc asp.net project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My project name called Hotel, and I want to create another project called Hotel2 containing all files of Hotel for testing purposes.
What are the steps to copy it without getting any errors?

Comment: Just copy the files to another folder?  Or branch them in source control?  What have you tried and in what way is it not working as expected?

Comment: Have you tried doing it? What difficulties you have faced while doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing this a few different ways.  I've found the safest way is to create a new project, add the files/components you need, and copy the contents of the files from project Hotel to the blank/default files in project Hotel2.

There is no fast and easy way to do it.  If you try any shortcuts, it almost always causes problems and more work.